# botBuilder-timeout module not recognize endConversation action

Tags: node.js, botframework

I have a issue with Usage of Botbuilder-timeout module.
I tried to add it to my Bot to trigger end of conversation if bot is inactive for certain time.I followed steps as per link "https://www.npmjs.com/package/botbuilder-timeout".
it works fine for inactivity. but if my conversation ends successfully with user action then also  time out triggers . 
so 
for example,
I have  set the setconversiontimeout for 30 seconds. so that for any given point  bot conversation is inactive for 30 seconds it will trigger a timeout action.
but if conversation happens properly and bot ends fine with user action like I am done with chatting. and my code triggers  session.endConversation();
but time out function does not recognize this end conversion and still ask to user if he is still there.and ends conversation which is already ended.

I am not sure what is going wrong.

can you please help what to do here. how I can accurately end conversation so that this timer can recognize it and dont end already ended conversation.

Answer (score 0):

Acturally, there is a bug in this module, please refer to the source code at https://github.com/User1m/botbuilder-timeout/blob/master/src/timeout.ts#L51, where source code is:
`_this.clearTimeoutHandlers(event);` which pass the `event` object to the functin.

However, the function definition is [`private clearTimeoutHandlers(convoId: string)`](https://github.com/User1m/botbuilder-timeout/blob/master/src/timeout.ts#L88) which require the `event.address.conversation.id`.

So you can directly modify the resource at `botbuilder-timeout/dist/timeout.js` at line 39 to:
`_this.clearTimeoutHandlers(convoId);`.

And I have apply a pull request to this repository at https://github.com/User1m/botbuilder-timeout/pull/3, if passed, you can update this module.

Comment: thanks for the input let me try this out and share the results here.